# Android - Admob - Loading ad then changing visibility causes problems

Tags: android, visibility, admob

Long version: I have an Android game. In each "screen" I'm showing the ads BUT the game screen itself - where you actually play. Now, if you launched the app-game (ad begins to load) and then clicked on "Start" before the ad has finished loading - it won't be shown when it should be (only a little strip of it)

Short version: Calling `AdView.loadAd` and then calling `AdView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` **before** the ad was received will yield a weird result if we call `AdView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` **after** the ad is loaded.

This happens:

[image]

Instead of, for example:

[image]

Now, clicking on this tiny strip left is **still** counted as clicking on the ad - clicking on it does whatever clicking on the ad would do (launching the browser and such...)

And should you go back to the home screen (I.E click the home button) then get back to the application, the ad is seen back again as it should.

Did anyone encouter it, and does anyone have any idea how to solve it? Thanks.

**EDIT:** Here is the relevant code:

Creating the ad view:

```
this.mAdView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "xxxxxxxxxxxxx");
```

Creating the layout params:

```
final FrameLayout.LayoutParams adViewLayoutParams =
            new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
```

Creating the root view group, and its layout params:

```
final FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
final FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameLayoutLayoutParams =
            new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
```

Adding to the root view group:

```
frameLayout.addView(this.mAdView, adViewLayoutParams);
```

And eventually, setting content view:

```
this.setContentView(frameLayout, frameLayoutLayoutParams);
```

Comment: What kind of code you're using to set the visibility of the ad? I mean, what is the design concept of your code? Where do you set the visibility and when? Also, provide your SDK version and adMob lib version. I've never seen anything like that.

Comment: I tried setting the View to be invisible but couldn't reproduce your issue.  Can you post some minimal code, particularly where you are adding the AdView in your layout?

Comment: Based on your solution of this (showing ad once its loaded) have you found that the initial impression will not be counted by AdMob since ad isn't visible for a fraction of a second until onAdLoaded event runs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to solve it in this way:

1. In the method which changes the visibility, I first check is the ad was loaded. If it was not, I don't change the visibility:
2. Set an AdListener for the AdView. in the onReceivedAd method, I check the condition to hide it - if it should be hidden, I hide.

Works fine this way.

Answer (score 5):

```
adContainer = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.adViewContainer);
    adContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    adContainer.addView(adView);
```

// your code for defining adView goes here.

```
adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            super.onAdLoaded();
            adContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to put the admobView inside an AbsoluteLayout and make the Invisible the full layout?

Comment: AbsoluteLayout is deprecated: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsoluteLayout.html