# Clipped Admob Banner

Tags: android, admob, surfaceview

I use SurfaceView for my game. I lastly added Admob banner by using following codes:

```
    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    layout.addView(renderView);

    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx");
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);

    layout.addView(adView);
    setContentView(layout);        

    adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

But my banner is seemed clipped as in the following image:

[image]

Later, if I press home button (or tab on banner) and return by pressing back button to my game, it is displayed normally as it can be seen the following image:

[image]

What is the problem?

Comment: Show Your XML for this screen

Comment: Which XML? AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Nope, the one in which You have Your adMob declared

Comment: I followed the instructions: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/quick-start
But I didn't perform activity_main.xml modification because I use
        adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
instead of 
'AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);

Comment: Maybe try inflating view with findByView if the first method doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found following link that includes the same problem and its solution:

[Android - Admob - Loading ad then changing visibility causes problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8171733/android-admob-loading-ad-then-changing-visibility-causes-problems)